# Bounded sequence in a normed space converges weakly

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Can anyone help me here?

Question: "X is a normed space and A is a subset dense in the dual of X.
x belongs to X and the sequence (x_n) of X is bounded of E such that f(x_n) converges to f(x) for all f in A. Show that x_n converges to x weakly"

My try: I think that if I show that  A=cl(A) so I prove what is required. So I have to prove that cl(A) is contained in A, ie, for all y in cl(A): y is in A.
Let y belongs to cl(A), ie, there existe a sequence (y_n) in A such that y_n converges to y.
Let y_n := f(x_n) and y:=f(x) (my doubt is: my I do this? because y is in A and f(x_n) is a image of x_n, and not a function)

Then I tried to prove that f(x) is in A but I think it's impossible :(

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to go about this. $A$ is dense in $X'$ so $cl(A) = X'$ and there are dense subspaces/sets without being the whole space. Try to approximate any element $f \in X'$ ($X'$ the dual space) by elements in $A$ and utilize the boundedness of ${x_n}$ and convergence of ${g(x_n)}$ for $g \in A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to prove

$g(x_n) \to g(x)$, for every $g \in X'$,

where $X'$ is the dual space of $X$. Equivalently, we can prove

$|g(x_n) - g(x)| \to 0$, as $n \to \infty$.

Let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence in $A$ such that

$\|f_k - g\|_{X'} = \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} |f_k(x) - g(x)| \to 0$, as $k \to \infty$.

The above implies that for each $x_n$ in the bounded sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$, we must have

$|f_k(x_n) - g(x_n)| \to 0$, as $k \to \infty$,

because the supremum goes to $0$ by the norm convergence of $\{f_k\}$.

Consider $|g(x_n) - g(x)|$, we have

$|g(x_n) - g(x)| = |g(x_n) - f_k(x_n) + f_k(x_n) - f_k(x) + f_k(x) - g(x)|$

$\leq |g(x_n) - f_k(x_n)| + |f_k(x_n) - f_k(x)| + |f_k(x) - g(x)|$.

Each term of the above sum goes to zero.

$|g(x_n) - f_k(x_n)| \to 0$ and $|f_k(x) - g(x)| \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ because of norm convergence of $\{f_k\}$ to $g$,

$|f_k(x_n) - f_k(x)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ by hypothesis.

So $|g(x_n) - g(x)| \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$ as desired.

Comment: Why do you considerer that the norm of g(x_n)-g(x) is the norm in X?
g is X dual so g(x_N) is real or complex...

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. It should be just the absolute value because the target spaces of linear functionals are always real or complex.

Comment: i dont understand your proof...why did you consider a sequence f_k in A such that...??

Comment: I want to pass the property that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ for all $f \in A$ from $A$ to the whole $X'$. Since $A$ is dense, meaning any element $g \in X'$ can be approximated by a sequence $\{f_k\}$ for $f_k \in A$, we use the approximating sequence to pass the property to $X'$.

Comment: hi!   thanks! ;) now i understand! :D

Answer (score 0):

You're on the wrong track because $A$ is never closed except in the trivial case where $A=X^*.$

You need to prove that for arbitrary $f\in X^*$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x).$$

You can do this using the $\epsilon$-definition of the limit of a sequence, first choosing a $g\in A$ sufficiently close to $f$ in the sense of the norm on $X^*$, then an $n$ sufficiently large, and use the triangle inequality (twice).